# Single word that defines a feeling of confidence that almost oozes out a person's pores

Tags: adjectives

The impression / feeling a celebrity might leave behind just walking by a group of fans or in a room after an appearance.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Arnold. Since your question seems to be answered according to your own comment below the answer you might think about accepting the answer.

Answer (score 4):

How about *Aura*?

> The meeting retains an aura of happiness even after the celebrity has
>   left.

The Free Dictionary defines Aura as:

> 1. An invisible emanation or field of energy believed to radiate from a person or object.
> 2. A distinctive but intangible quality that seems to surround a person or thing; an atmosphere.

Comment: He had a certain aura about him. Yes perfect. Thx

Comment: Aura is good if you are speaking of a person you admire.  Cocky or cocksure for same attitude in one you distain

Comment: @Kris The OP has mentioned in the question about "fans". So fans typically admire the person. That's the reason behind suggesting Aura as an answer.

Comment: You are correct I popped off with only having read the title    @Arnold  how about a green check mark for Nags homework help?